# Running Node.js script from React in order to send an email

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to this issue, new to Node.js as well, so I'm facing quite I suppose typical case.

I have a quite simple form in React.js and when the user presses 'submit' button I need to connect it to Node file with form values which will send it to my email. I'm not sure how to connect React and Node on request, ie. send values to and import it in Node.

Here's my react side code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            color: '#000000',
            nameValue: '',
            emailValue: '',
            textareaValue: '',
        };
    }

    handleName(e) {
        this.setState({ nameValue: e.target.value });
    }

    handleEmail(e) {
        this.setState({ emailValue: e.target.value });
    }

    handleTextarea(e) {
        this.setState({ textareaValue: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    handldeHoverOn() {
        this.setState({ 
            backgroundColor: '#c91010',
            color: '#ffffff' 
        });
    }

    handleHoverOut() {
        this.setState({ 
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            color: '#000000'
         });
    }

    render() {
        const styles = {
            formStyle: {
                margin: '2rem 0',
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'center'
            },
            containerStyle: {
                width: '80%',
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            },
            nameStyle: {
                width: '100%',
                height: '2rem',

            },
            emailStyle: {
                width: '100%',
                height: '2rem',
                marginLeft: '2rem',
            },
            textareaStyle: {
                margin: '2rem 0',
                width: '80%',
                height: '5rem',
                boxSizing: 'border-box',
            },
            submitStyle: {
                backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor,
                width: '10rem',
                height: '2rem',
                border: '0.5px solid grey',
                borderRadius: '5px',
                textTransform: 'uppercase',
                color: this.state.color,
                cursor: 'pointer'
            }
        };
        const { formStyle, 
                nameStyle, 
                containerStyle, 
                textareaStyle, 
                emailStyle, 
                submitStyle } = styles;

        return (
            <form style={formStyle}> 
                <div style={containerStyle}>
                    <input 
                        style={nameStyle} 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Imię i nazwisko" 
                        onChange={e => this.handleName(e)} 
                        value={this.state.nameValue}
                    />
                    <input 
                        style={emailStyle} 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Email" 
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleEmail(e)}
                        value={this.state.emailValue}
                    />
                </div>
                <textarea 
                    style={textareaStyle} 
                    placeholder="Wiadomość" 
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleTextarea(e)}
                    value={this.state.textareaValue}
                />
                <input
                    type="submit"
                    value="WYŚLIJ" 
                    style={submitStyle} 
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)} 
                    onMouseOver={() => this.handldeHoverOn()} 
                    onMouseOut={() => this.handleHoverOut()}
                />            
            </form>

        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

And Node side:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');

const generator = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
      type: 'OAuth2',
      user: 'X',
      clientId: 'X',
      clientSecret: 'X',
      refreshToken: 'X'
  }
})

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'x@gmail.com',
  to: 'x@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Mail',
  text: 'test text'
}

generator.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, res){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error')
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent')
  }
})
```

Comment: Your node backend is a completely different program that is not necessarily running on the same machine as your react app. It does not share any runtime information with your react app which is running in a browser. To exchange information between the client (react-app) and the server (node-app) you need to send everything as a network request to the server. You could e.g. setup an [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) web server.

Comment: +1 to @trixn . You have to create an API at backend. React is a client side technology, and not supposed to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to do that.

It's using API instead of running a whole server for that.

I recommend you to checkout [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) service.

The example below is for sending multiple emails and will work for your react app, too.

```
export function sendEmail(key, sender, email1 ,email2) {
  const url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send"; // sendGrid v3 api

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${key}`, // your API_KEY here
    "Content-type": 'application/json',
  };

  const data = {
    personalization: [email1, email2],
    from: {
      email: sender,
    },
    content: [
      {
        type: "text/plain",
        value: "{{content}}" // little trick for custom value
      }
    ],
  };

  const request = {
    method: "post",
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }

  return fetch(url, request)
   .then(response => response.json());
}

// example param: email1
const email1 = {
  to: [{
    email: recipient1,
  }],
  subject: subject1,
  substitutions: {
    "{{content}}": body, // mail body
  }
}
```

Comment: does not work from react. you get CORS issues: "Fetch API cannot load https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send due to access control checks"